# Create Grid in Magento Edit Customer

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I would like to create a grid and add/edit form in magento customer edit page.

I have successfully created new tab in customer edit page. On my previous practices, I have created a grid and forms on the top menu but not on the customer page.

QUESTION:

How to create a grid and form in customer edit page? it is similar to billing agreement grid, news letter grid, wishlist grid.

The process should be like this.

1. The admin will choose a customer and click it.
2. On the edit page, the admin will navigate to a custom tab that display a grid and button.
3. The grid display some details like title, short description and others.
4. the admin can add some list that is only available to that customer.
5. the newly added list will be added to the grid